# Facebook SDK sharedialog on xamarin (c#)

Tags: c#, facebook, xamarin, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to open Facebook share dialog in Xamarin using c#, I have implanted the Facebook sdk following the getting started link from https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookandroid.

Xamarin don't recognize Sharedialog command as mentioned in Facebook documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#share_dialog

Any advice on how to trigger the window ? or a working simple in xamarin ?

Answer (score 1):

it is in the path  `Xamarin.Facebook.Share.Widget.ShareDialog.`

and you can just import with:

```
using Xamarin.Facebook.Share.Widget;
```

Cheers